# React: Add class to child of imported component

Tags: reactjs

i'm using imported component, that gives me some text input field

```
import {TextField} from package;

const myForm = () => {

    return (
        <TextField name="name" .../>
    );
}
```

In html this TextField looks like div container with input:

```
<div>
    <input name="name" id="id" value="">
</div>
```

I need to add some className to input for styles

my problem is that if i add a className for the TextField component

```
<TextField name="name" className="classCss".../>
```

he added for div container, not for input

```
<div class="classCss">
    <input name="name" id="id" value="">
</div>
```

As i understand, i need variant to iterate all childs of this component and replace them with cloned child with className

something like this:

```
<TextField ...>
    {
        this.props.children.map((el, index) => {
            return React.cloneElement(el, {
                key: index,
                className: el.className + " classCss"
            });
        })
    }
</TextField>
```

but how i can take access to childs (and props) for imported component?

Comment: You may can share what package you are using exactly, and check their docs if there is the way to custom input.
And the other way, you can just style to nested input in the css file `.yourClassName input { --- Your style is here --- } `

Comment: @ClusterH 
it is atlaskit textfield: https://atlassian.design/components/textfield/code


i want to keep it simple, and just use existing classes.


as workaround, of course, i can just use simple <input>, but i'm interest in answer, about changing child of existing imported component. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try using `styles` prop?

Comment: If the module you are using does not provide you a way to access children, then why you don't select it via css children? ".classCss > input" will select the input, then you can style it

Comment: he main question was about accessing the child elements of an imported component. So we can't do that, right?